# Android: locale(system Language) change effect my application layouts

Tags: android, locale

i'm in my app, one activity is opened. I press home button and change language, from taskmanager opens my app. Problem: my activity layout is getting wide.

changes in androidmanifest corresponding to that activity:

Note: If i add locale in android manifest, layout is proper, but language is not getting updated immediately. User have to close that activity and then restart, only then language is getting updated.

Please provide me your inputs.

Comment: That's the normal behavior. When you start your application, your device says "Hey! I'm using that Locale so please provide the right resources...". Then, when you change Local while your application is already started, it's too late because the right resources have already been loaded. So you HAVE to reload.

Comment: Do i need to add locale attribute also in android manifest?

Comment: Absolutely not. By default, the used local is your device's one.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment on your question, it is normal behaviour.

A change in Locale is considered a change of Configuration the same as a change in orientation etc.

You need to override [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)  in your `Activity` and reload everything from there.

NOTE: You will also need to specify `android:configChanges="locale"` in the `Activity` declaration in the `AndroidManifest` file.

Comment: I have some problem i tried to overide onConfigurationChanged but it isn't called in Fragment Activity when i change locale

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Arabic and English languages are using in my app. When changing the language to Arabic then, it shows arabic strings in activity pages but it show still english in fragmet pages.