# Android : Setting language in app

Tags: android, localization

I want to change my app language in my app because android languages don't have all languages i want to use. So i got this to change:

```
String languageToLoad  = "en";  
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);   
Locale.setDefault(locale);  
Configuration config = new Configuration();  
config.locale = locale;  
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,   
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

However, when user opens app and change it. Then strings which is showing at that moment still are the older language it changes just when new `Activity` is created.

Other problem that i should somehow save what user language was select and then change language when app is started.

So how to improve this? I want that when user select language all strings would be taken from selection languages strings.xml and how to save which language user was selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SharedPreference to store the user's language. Here's the documentation about it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

About the need to reload the Activity, you may find some answers here: [Android: locale(system Language) change effect my application layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751107/android-localesystem-language-change-effect-my-application-layouts#comment13972019_10751107)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public class (`public class Share`) with static members like `public static String language = "en";` You can easily access the fields of this class with using the code as `Share.language` in whole of your project. If you want to change the language you can set `Share.language = "fa";`. To reload the activity with selected language, you should place the following code before any activitie's `super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);` :

```
Locale l = new Locale(Shares.language);
Locale.setDefault(l);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = l;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources()
        .updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Please note that, language can be set, if you have a folder like `values-language` in your `/res` folder.

Good luck, Hossein :)