# setLocale method - updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration.androidtil.DisplayMetcis) is deprecated

Tags: android, android-resources, android-configchanges

I got the `setLocale` method for Android from this thread [Change languages in app via strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573201/change-languages-in-app-via-strings-xml). The problem is that Android Studio says that `locale is deprecated`, And 
`updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration.androidtil.DisplayMetcis) is deprecated`.

Does anyone know the work around?

```
/*- Set locale ------------------------------------------------------------ */
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Resources.updateConfiguration` is now deprecated, avoid directly changing the `conf.locale` field. From API 24 use:

```
conf.setLocale(locale);
```