# Locale Changing within app is not working

Tags: java, android, locale

I am trying to change the language of the app but it's not happening.I have tried almost all solutions available in SO but none worked. Interesting fact is most of the codes are able to change the language of the Facebook Account Kit activity but other activity's language is not being changed.Below is my application class and manifest file.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {


    private Locale locale = null;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null)
        {
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

        new SharedPrefManager(this).setLanguage("fr");
        String lang = new SharedPrefManager(this).getLanguage();

        locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        AccountKit.initialize(getApplicationContext());
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.pullerr.pullerrdriver">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.FacebookAppEventsEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppLoginTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme"/>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
            android:name=".LoadDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOADDETAILS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="services.LocationService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: Facebook AccountKit Language is Changed]

Comment: it is not going to change automatically with locale you need to add your words in string.xml

Comment: Can you show me a demo please?

Comment: create a new values folder for the language you are going to add translated string files, for example, if you need hindi create a new folder inside res like "values-hi" and add a string file inside this with default translations in hindi

Comment: yes I have seen a project in Github where this was done. what should be the name of the string. I mean <string name="??">My App</string>

That means every single text has to be mentioned in the strings.xml file? can hard code it anywhere?

Comment: check the links you'll understand

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181847/change-the-locale-at-runtime/

Answer (score 1):

check this links maybe it helps

[How to programmatically change language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454353/how-to-programmatically-change-language)

http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/change-language-programmatically-android-app-building-multi-language-supported-app/

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

[Change languages in app via strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573201/change-languages-in-app-via-strings-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your language (i18N) as below :

```
public static void changeLanguage(String language, Context context) {
    try {
        if ( null != language) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language); 
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Language changed to " + language);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "[changeLanguage]" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I have one open-source project on [GitHub](https://github.com/configurer/easy-screen-lock/blob/master/EasyScreenLock/src/com/configurer/easyscreenlock/). Drive-in yourself at https://github.com/configurer/easy-screen-lock/blob/master/EasyScreenLock/src/com/configurer/easyscreenlock/utils/LanguageUtils.java

Comment: I use similar code. On my andrid-4.4 it only worked if the call to `changeLanguage(..)` was made **before** calling `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Yes app restart is required to effect the locale changes.