# How to change text value using Strings.xml - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, string, locale

I Created Body Mass Index App, in that app, some text says, **Please input your height** etc.

I set it using `Strings.xml`, In my case, I want to be able to switch the language from the text **Please input your height** into another language, Any Solution?

Comment: Refer this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573201/change-language-in-android-application-using-string-file**

Comment: Check my answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, create one Resources objects for each locale you need. Then,
>   fetch the strings from the localized Resources object.

**You can write a method like:**

```
@NonNull Resources getLocalizedResources(Context context, Locale myLocale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf = new Configuration(conf);
    conf.setLocale(myLocale);
    Context localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(conf);
    return localizedContext.getResources();
}
```

**You can call the method like:**

```
Locale filipinoLocale = new Locale("fil");
Resources filipinoResource = getLocalizedResources(context, filipinoLocale);

Locale russianLocale = new Locale("ru");
Resources russianResource = getLocalizedResources(context, russianLocale);

Locale chineseLocale = new Locale("zh");
Resources chineseResource = getLocalizedResources(context, chineseLocale);

String filipinoString = filipinoResource.getString(R.string.mystring);
String russianString = russianResource.getString(R.string.mystring);
String chineseString = chineseResource.getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Answer (score 2):

the nice thing with string.xml is that if you create a new folder value-"the language that you want" like this one in your res folder[image]

Is that like in this exemple the language of the app is going to set itself to english or french in my case base on the language use on the cellphone you just need to have the same string name and you can change the value to wathever you want :)

[image]

[image]